# Phaser 3: Finish loading json before Scene.preload() gets called

Tags: phaser-framework

I want to describe my scenes in a JSON file, and then preload images etc. according to the contents of that JSON file. So the content of the JSON file needs to have been fully loaded  before entering preload. I don't know how to do this. I've created a minimal, reproducible [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0fmg6ye/2/) that logs `preload: undefined` when `prepreload = true`.
For `prepreload = false` I get `create: [object Object]`.

```js
var prepreload = true
var config = { scene: { init: init, preload: preload, create: create } }
var game = new Phaser.Game(config)

function init(config) {
    if (prepreload) {
        this.load.json('scenedata', 'scene.json');    
        this.load.start();
    }
}

function preload () {
    if (prepreload)
        console.log(this.cache.json.get("scenedata"));
    else
        this.load.json('scenedata', 'scene.json');    
}

function create () {
    if (!prepreload)
        console.log(this.cache.json.get("scenedata"));
}
```

Any idea how to preload images according to the contents of a JSON file - ideally all inside the Scene class, rather than doing it externally and passing it into the `init` method or similar.

Comment: Can you share the JSON content or part of it so that it can be repro'd?

Comment: Just a guess... but how about `this.load.onLoadComplete.add(this.load.start(), this);`

Comment: @Nelloverflow The content is irrelevant to the problem. But I have created a jsfiddle to reproduce.

Comment: @DennyMueller Unless I am misunderstanding the docs, [`start()`](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Loader.LoaderPlugin.html#start__anchor) is used to start loading, and the [`COMPLETE`](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Loader.Events.html#event:COMPLETE) event is raised when loading has finished, in other words, you are confusing chicken and egg. But you can prove me wrong in the jsfiddle I just added to the question.

Comment: Ye you are right that missread by me...  Dug into the source of Scene and it seems like if you want to to preload outside of `preload()` then you have to overwrite some callback behavior.
https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/v3.51.0/src/scene/SceneManager.js#L450

as you can see preload specifically waits for the loader to finish `loader.once(LoaderEvents.COMPLETE, this.loadComplete, this);` 

Additionally you can see that before `preload()` no internal loader behavior is triggered.

Comment: @DennyMueller Thanks for pointing me to the source code - studying it led me to a solution, as detailed in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SettingsConfig` can be used for that - the files listed under `pack` will already have been loaded when entering the `init` method.

Here's how it can be done (Phaser 3.55.2):

```js
var config = { 
  scene: { 
    init: init, 
    preload: preload,
    create: create,
    pack: { 
      "files": [
        { type: 'json', key: 'scene', url: 'scene.json' }
      }
    }
  }
}
var game = new Phaser.Game(config)
```

Here's a slightly different variant, using TypeScript:

```js
export class TestScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({ pack: {
            "files": [ { type: 'json', key: 'scene', url: 'scene.json' }
```